# How to Modify Alternatives to Quick Build in TeXMaker

Tags: texmaker

I just got started using TeX Maker, and I am playing with the Quick Build option.  I saw that at the bottom of the menue where one can select quick build there are also options 1: - 5:.

[image: Various options besides Quick Build]
However, I am not sure how to customize these.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to alter these?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The main reason I want to alter these options is that for shorter assignments I don't want to use my standard quick build, but dont want to just change quick build over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to User  --> User commands --> Edit user commands. You can type in command line instructions manually, or use the "wizard" button.